# Find number of customers year by year

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many informations about my customers, in summary :

| id | dateInscription | specialite | dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-04-09 | Anesthesiology | 75 |
| 2 | 2004-02-16 | Neurology | 62 |
| 3 | 1999-01-01 | Pathology | 34 |
| 4 | 2016-05-13 | Family medicine | 59 |

I want to calculate the total number of customer by year, Speciality and country code.

I already find a way to calculate the NEW customer with this query, but not the total :

```
SELECT
    YEAR(dateInscription) as 'Annee_inscription',
    a.specialite,
    a.dept as 'Departement',
    COUNT(a.id) as 'NOMBRE_PS'
FROM
    customers a
WHERE
    YEAR(dateInscription) IN(2013,
    2015,
    2017,
    2019,
    2021)
    AND a.specialite IN ('ANATOMIE ET CYTOLOGIE PATHOLOGIQUES',
    'ANESTHESIE-REANIMATION',
    'BIOLOGIE MEDICALE',
    'CARDIOLOGIE/PATHOLOGIE CARDIO-VASCULAIRE')
GROUP BY
    Annee_inscription,
    a.specialite ,
    Departement
ORDER BY
    Annee_inscription ASC,
    a.specialite ASC,
    Departement ASC
```

In the best world, i want an output like this :

| Year_range | specialite | dept | number_customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999-2004 | Anesthesiology | 01 | 10 |
| 1999-2004 | Anesthesiology | 02 | 13 |
| 1999-2004 | Anesthesiology | 03 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... | .... |
| 1999-2004 | Family medicine | 01 | 124 |
| 1999-2004 | Family medicine | 02 | 514 |
| 1999-2004 | Family medicine | 03 | 1284 |
| ... | ... | ... | .... |
| 1999-2006 | Anesthesiology | 01 | 15 |
| 1999-2006 | Anesthesiology | 02 | 17 |
| 1999-2006 | Anesthesiology | 03 | 29 |
| ... | ... | ... | .... |

i try to group by case but with no good result.

Pro tip : i dont have the write right on this database

In advance a big thank to you.

Comment: How do you extract the "*Year_range*" values from your input table?

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve this problem is to:

- first transform your "*dateInscription*" input field to the corresponding "*Year_range*" output field (by extracting the minimum and maximum year partitioned by "*specialite*" values)
- then apply your aggregation on the "*Year_range*" field, as well as "*specialite*" and "*dept*" fields

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CONCAT_WS('-', 
                     MIN(YEAR(dateInscription)) OVER(PARTITION BY specialite),
                     MAX(YEAR(dateInscription)) OVER(PARTITION BY specialite)) AS Year_range
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Year_range,
       specialite,
       dept,
       COUNT(*) AS number_customer
FROM cte
GROUP BY Year_range,
         specialite, 
         dept
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oPaK8uEVLAgpA465MVgwmU/0).

Note: the demo will allow you to play with the query, though for a better troubleshooting, more input data and corresponding expected output may be required.